# continuous functions problem

Tags: limits, functions

[image]

I dont understand, isn't this function already continuous on (−∞,∞)

Comment: In general, no. It depends on $a$.

Comment: What is the limit as $t \uparrow -5$ and $t \downarrow -5$.

Comment: Certainly not, as $f(-5^+)$ varies with $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont understand, isn't this function already continuous on (−∞,∞)

It is indeed continuous everywhere, **except** possibly at $x=-5$. There, the continuity depends on the value of (the parameter) $a$.

Now the question is: find the value of (this parameter) $a$ so that the function is indeed continuous at $x=-5$ (and thus, everywhere).

Now rely on the definition and/or relevant properties of continuity you know (think limits!).